# What is this Network Security Alert about?

Tags: windows-10, security, alert

The apps I had running when this alert popped up are:

- Google Chrome
- Mic Word
- Sticky Notes
- SQL Developer

I woke my computer up from sleep to find this error in the middle of my screen.

[image]

Comment: "I woke my computer up from sleep to find this error in the middle of my screen." - This is associated with your wireless connection to your network.  It is linked to a RADIUS network connection. It appears you have conflicting access points, at the very least, you are attempting to connect to a poorly configured network.

Comment: [Windows Security Alert appears when connecting to a wireless network on a workgroup machine](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2518158/windows-security-alert-appears-when-connecting-to-a-wireless-network-o).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! If you put your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the screenshot, it is certificate relate alert. In general, for security enabled/configured network, certificate is used for network access authentication. If it is not matched, or, something wrong configuration, may cause similar problem.

If it is the case, you may try to request certificate for your computer, or, contact the network admin to check the details.